# WordPress dashboard

Tags: theme-development

I am working towards developing a WordPress them from an HTML/CSS template on my local machine. But after activating the theme from the WordPress dashboard and clicking the Visit Site link, I am unable to view the WordPress bar for the dashboard. Kindly guide on what needs to be done.

Thanks and regards

Debashis

Answer (score 1):

All themes must include `wp_footer` and `wp_head` calls. If you don't add these, then there's no way for WordPress to insert the necessary html/js/css, functions like wp_enqueue_style will not work, SEO plugins will have no effect, etc etc etc

`wp_head` goes inside the head tags, and wp_footer should go at the end of the template, ideally just before the closing body tag.

It's also possible that you have simply turned off the admin toolbar using the option in your user settings. Changing that may re-enable it ( assuming you have done the steps with `wp_head` and `wp_footer` )

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just typing in the URL for the dashboard?

http://www.yoursitename.com/wp-admin/

If that lets you into the admin area then you can do....

Users > your profile > check Show Toolbar when viewing site

Comment: That is already done. But I still can't view the toolbar. Thanks!